# Could not open input file: zf.php

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am new in zend, so i installed zfTool from [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zendtool.introduction.html)

I use the composer for installing the tool, the command is :

```
composer require zendframework/zftool:dev-master
```

But when i run the command : `php zf.php version`

For example i got this error : `Could not open input file: zf.php`
so please if someone has any idea i will be very appreciative.

Comment: See https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/vendor-binaries.md, and check the `vendor/bin` directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you downloaded using composer, you can access the command line of `ZfTool` as:

```
vendor/bin/zf.php
```

For example, to get version:

```
vendor/bin/zf.php version
```