# Zend Framework Tool - zf.php: command not found

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-tool

I'm trying to install Zend Framework Tool.

I follow the documentation and when I run `zf.php modules` (as stated in the docs) I get `zf.php: command not found`

I found someone who was having a similar problem here - [Could not open input file: zf.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21829616/could-not-open-input-file-zf-php)

..so from that post I tried the alternative (from my project directory - /var/www/zf-tutorial) `vendor/bin/zf.php modules` and it successfully lists my modules.

Why is this inconstant with the documentation? Do I have to write out this whole path every time?

==

So next, when trying to CREATE a project using Zend Tool, naturally I feel I need to navigate out of the project directory to my all projects directory (/var/www)

So I try `zf2-tutorial/vendor/bin/zf.php create project zendtest` from there... and I get the error (seems strange anyway that I might run a script of another project to create a new one but I'm just trying figure things out for now):

```
Error: I cannot find the autoloader of the application.
Check if /var/www contains a valid ZF2 application.
```

OK, seems I need to be within my projects directory where I installed it? So, grudgingly I go back into my projects directory (/var/www/zf2-tutorial) and run it from there - which seems even stranger that I should create a project from within another project... but it seems to work, .. but no, as it puts it inside my zf2-tutorial directory as that is where I am (thought it might)

How do I use this tool? Ideally I'd like to install it once and have it available for ALL projects current and future. Is simply `zf create projects` too possible? `zf.php ...` just seems messy

Comment: Is it executable? `chmod +x zf.php` Have you tried running it with php? `php zf.php`

Comment: Yeh it's executable (I run your line just to be sure) but it wouldn't run by `vendor/bin/zf.php modules` either if it weren't, no?